# Change Database Structure on Table being Replicated

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

I need to make structure changes to a database that is part of a subscription that is using Transactional Replication.

I am wondering if I take the Database out of the Article list, make the changes on the Master server then do a Snapshot to reinitialize the subscribers.

Will that work, or is there something else I should do to get this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I think SQL Server 2005 replicates schema changes as well. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151870.aspx